# Solving $L - L\sqrt{1-\frac{u^2}{C^2}} = u T$ for $u$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Hello how can i solve this for $u$ ($L,C,T$ are constants).

\begin{aligned}
L - L\sqrt{1-\frac{u^2}{C^2}} = u T
\end{aligned}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\text{Rearranging: }L-uT=L\sqrt{1-\frac{u^{2}}{C^{2}}}$$
$$\text{Squaring both sides: }(L-uT)^{2}=L^{2}\left(1-\frac{u^2}{C^{2}}\right)$$
$$\text{Expanding our squares: }L^{2}-2LuT+u^{2}T^{2}=L^{2}-\frac{u^{2}L^{2}}{C^{2}}$$
$$\text{Cancelling $L^{2}$, and collecting coefficients: }\left(\frac{L^{2}}{C^{2}}+T^{2}\right)u^{2}=2LTu$$
If $u$ is not zero, we can divide by it (and if it is, then our orginal equation becomes $L=L$), so:
$$\text{Bringing our fraction over a common denominator: }\left(\frac{L^{2}+C^{2}T^{2}}{C^{2}}\right)u=2LT$$
$$\text{Multiplying by its reciprocal}\implies u=\frac{2LTC^{2}}{L^{2}+C^{2}T^{2}}$$

In general, when solving algebraic expressions it is generally best to consider *what is in the way*, and get rid of the most difficult expressions first. In this case, the square root is the most unpleasant expression, so we square both sides to eliminate it. Bring all our terms with $u$ together allowed us certain cancellations which made the overall procedure easier.

Comment: instead of dividing by $u$ from $$ \left(\frac{L^{2}}{C^{2}}+T^{2}\right)u^{2}=2LTu ,$$ it is typically taught to factor the expression as $$u \left( \left(\frac{L^{2}}{C^{2}}+T^{2}\right)u - 2LT \right) = 0 .$$ This avoids the issue of dividing a variable - though, addressing the issue by separating the cases of $u=0$ and $u \neq 0$ is perfectly valid too.